# Page Protect attribute in XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo, oracle-apex-19.2

I need to implement XSL-FOP layout like attached image.

first Parent table "Requested Items Information". Inside there is a Child table"Item Name" and inside of it another child table"Technical Information" in that will have multiple records.

Now when page breaks then all parent tables headers should display along with grand child table name.

Attached image Second page start with "Requested Items Information" then "Item Name" then "Technical Information".

This is achieved "Page Protect" property in RDF. Now i need to implement it in XSL-FOP.

I tried **page-break-inside="avoid"** attribute but all the data is coming only in one page once page is fill then rest of data is not visible which means data is not at all coming to second page.

I tried **keep-together="always"** attribute but table content is not wrapping. data is exceeding pdf width size. However next page is not coming as needed.

Thanks in advance for suggestions and advises

[image: Need to implement PDF like this image]

Below is Code.

```
<fo:block margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left" >
       <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm">
          <fo:table-column column-width="200mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.1mm" />          
          <fo:table-body>
             <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                   <fo:block margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                      Requested Items Information
                   </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                    <fo:block margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                            
                       <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm">
                          <fo:table-column column-width="200mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.1mm" />          
                          <fo:table-body>
                             <fo:table-row height="0.2cm" border-bottom-style="solid" border-width="0.1mm">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                                   <fo:block margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                                      Item Name: 
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                                   <fo:block margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                                      <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm">
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="42mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="25mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />                                   
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="35mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="30mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="38mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                      <fo:table-column column-width="30mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                      <fo:table-body>
                                         <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                                            <fo:block margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                                                  <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm">
                                                      <fo:table-column column-width="200mm" border-style="solid" border-width="0.0mm" />
                                                      <fo:table-body>
                                                          <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                                                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                                                               <fo:block margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                                                                  Technical Information
                                                               </fo:block>                                                             
                                                            </fo:table-cell>                                                                                                                
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                         <fo:table-row height="0.2cm">
                                                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1">
                                                               <fo:block margin-left="0.2cm" margin-right="0.0cm" margin-top="0.2cm" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" color="#000000" text-align="left">
                                                                 description
                                                               </fo:block>                                                             
                                                            </fo:table-cell>                                                                                                                        
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </fo:table-body>
                                                </fo:table>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                      </fo:table-body>
                                      </fo:table>                                  
                                   </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                      </fo:table>   
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>                
             </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
       </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

fo:table-header is working for the issue. Thanks Tony.

However I am having an issue when page break Table is visible like broken.[image]
Is there any way to close table when page breaks?

Comment: Please show at least some of your XSL-FO markup so that we can see what you are doing that doesn't work for you.  Are you using `fo:table-header` for the 'Technical Information' and other headers?

Comment: `keep-together="always"` means "keep this piece of content in the same page **and in the same line**"; `keep-together.within-page="always"` is probably what you should be using instead.

Comment: Thanks For Quick replies. Code is added.

Comment: Keep nesting the tables as you have done for the outer one

Comment: Thanks Tony. "fo:table-header" is solution for my issue.